# ngrx - merge data

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I Just learn **ngrx**, can't understand How to change model/merge, just simple changes.
I got data in ngOnInit:

> this.store.dispatch(new GetHeroes());
>
> this.heroes$ = this.store.select(fromSelectors.getParticipants);
>
> this.store.dispatch(new GetClients());
>
> this.clients$ = this.store.select(fromSelectors.getClients);

Before display **heroes$ data in HTML**, I need to **this.heroes$.push({name: 'newName'})** and **this.heroes$.push(this.clients$[0])**
But my models looks like: **Store: { actionsObserver: { ....}}**

I am totally confused, help please how to do it following the REDUX rules

**Just some store files:**

```js
//hero.actions.ts
...
export enum HeroActionTypes {
  heroGetHeroes = '[Hero] get',
  heroGetHeroesSuccess = '[Hero] get heroes success',
  .....
}


export class GetHeroes implements Action {
  readonly type = HeroActionTypes.heroGetHeroes;
}
export class GetHeroesSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = HeroActionTypes.heroGetHeroesSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: Hero[]) {}
}

//hero.effects.ts
...
  @Effect()
  loadHeroes$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(HeroActionTypes.heroGetHeroes),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.heroService
        .getHeroes()
        .pipe(
          map(heroes => new GetHeroesSuccess(heroes)),
          catchError(error => of(new HeroError(error)))
        )
    )
  );
// hero.reducer.ts
switch (action.type) {
    case HeroActionTypes.heroGetHeroes:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case HeroActionTypes.heroGetHeroesSuccess:
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload, {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true
      });
// hero.selectors.ts
export const getHeroes = createSelector(getHeroEntities, entities => {
  return Object.values(entities);
});
```

also almost identical code for Clients

Answer (score 1):

> I need to this.heroes$.push({name: 'newName'}) and this.heroes$.push(this.clients$[0])

This is where it all went wrong. You don't have to do this, and you shouldn't do this.
The only place where the state can be changed is inside the reducers.

To solve your problem you must dispatch a success action from your effects with the data as its payload, like you already do. A dispatched action from your effect gets passes through your reducer where you can return a new state. I see that you're using `@ngrx/entity`, meaning the `addAll` function will add the new entities to your state.

Where exactly does it go wrong, or did you need an explanation of the action flow? Because your snippets are valid.